# Cannot Set Mockito Value in Junit TestCase for Controller

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Here is my **Controller Class:**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/administration", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView adminstrationPage(HttpServletRequest request){
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    mv.setViewName("administration");

    Optional<User> uo = userRepository.findOneByName(request.getUserPrincipal().getName());
    ... return mv;
}
```

Here is my **LoginControllerTest**:

```
    @InjectMocks
        LoginController loginController;

        @Mock
        private LoginService loginService;

        @Mock
        private UserRepository userRepository;

        @Mock
        User user;

        MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Test
        public void administartion() throws Exception{

Mockito.when(userRepository.findOneByName("test")).thenReturn(Optional.of(user));

            mockMvc.perform(get("/administration"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
        }
```

Now getting nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException. Please help me.

Comment: Please paste complete code of LoginControllerTest.java

Comment: Did you annotate your class with @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) as suggested at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mockito/mockito_junit_integration.htm

Comment: What is the point in calling setters on a mock? Makes no sense to me.

Comment: I have updated my code... but still same problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

When mocking user repository, instead of `userRepository.findOneByName("")`
try `userRepository.findOneByName(anyString())`.
And don't forget to init mocks in before method, `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);`

Comment: I have checked with userRepository.findOneByName(anyString()) and use MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); into before method but still same problem. NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     user.setId(100000L);
>     user.setName("testName");
>     user.setEmail("testEmail@gmail.com");
> ```

Since `user` is a **mock** these statements are useless.

Either create a real `User` object (which is prefered if it is a simple DTO) or define the `user` mocks behavior using `when(user.getXXX()).thenhReturn(xxx)` or `doReturn(xxx).when(user).getXXX();`

Comment: I have commented those lines and checked again but still nullPointerException. have any idea?

Comment: @Amit what sense does it make to comment *useless lines* and expect any change?